# Процентная ставка по вкладу составляет P процентов годовых. Определите размер вклада через год

Tags: c++, математика, числа-с-плавающей-точкой

Задача:
Процентная ставка по вкладу составляет P процентов годовых, которые прибавляются к сумме вклада в конце года. Вклад составляет X рублей Y копеек. Определите размер вклада через год.

**Правильный ответ**: 200 и 48.

**Мой ответ**: 200 и 47.

В чём может быть проблема?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  int procent;
  double vkladR, vkladRtoK, vkladK;
  cin >> procent >> vkladR >> vkladK;
  vkladR = vkladR * procent / 100  + vkladR; // находим вклад в рублях через год
  vkladRtoK = vkladR - int(vkladR); // находим количество копеек из полученных рублей
  vkladR = vkladR - vkladRtoK; // получаем чистые рубли без копеек
  vkladK = vkladK * procent / 100 + vkladK + int(vkladRtoK * 100);
  cout << vkladR << " " << vkladK;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Да в округлении небось... получаешь чёнить типа 0,479999999.

Comment: А если `vkladK` будет больше ста?

Comment: Спасибо за ваши ответы и советы, я подумал и нашёл несколько решений. Можно продолжить канитель с моим кодом из рублей в копейки, а можно перевести всё в копейки с дальнейшим переводом в рубли, что значительно проще! Конкретно мой код не работает из-за того, что существует погрешность в округлении, как подметил(а) Akina. Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У вас вообще странное вычисление...

Не проще ли

```
double vklad = vkladR*100 + vkladK;
vklad *= (1+procent/100.0);
cout << floor(vklad/100) << "  " << round(vklad - 100*floor(vklad/100)) << endl;
```

Тем более, что, как справедливо замечено, копейки с процентами могут перерасти в рубли - например, для

```
12 179 99
```

ваш код дает

```
200  157.88
```

в то время как верный ответ -

```
201  59
```

(ну, или 58 - не знаю, как банк округлит 58.88 - до 58 или до 59... я в своем коде считал, что до 59).